# Boost 1.84.0 Serialization and System Libraries don't come with Jamfiles, how do I build these libraries?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, build

The serialization and system libraries for Boost 1.84.0 did not come with a Jamfile in their root folder structure (libs/serialization) which the others do. So, when I go to run b2 to build the libraries, it can't find the Jamfile and fails.

There are, however, other Jamfiles labeled Jamfile.v2 in the libs/serialization/build folder. Can I build the folders off those? Or will that mess things up?

Tried just using CMake to build it because I noticed a CMakeFile.txt file in the libaries, but threw other errors.

**Update**
The issue is also present with Boost 1.82.0.

Comment: Just follow the build instructions https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/more/getting_started/index.html shouldn't need to change anything if you're using a common platform. Please show the exact steps you've done and the full text of any error messages

Comment: Hi Alan I am using a Windows 10 64 architecture. I downloaded the 1.84.0 windows binaries from source forge. From that I ran the install program. It finished. I then followed the instructions on that website to build b2. The only thing I didn't do was not add the PREFIX/bin folder to my PATH environmental variable, because that folder did not get created inside of PREFIX. I only have PREFIX/include and PREFIX/lib. Anyway, then I went to the folder inside of this folder boost_1_84_0\libs\iostreams and ran b2 to build iostreams which worked. I did the same for the progress_options library.

Comment: This is the error message I get when I tell b2 to build the serialization or the system library: `C:\local\boost_1_84_0\libs\system>..\..\b2
error: no Jamfile in current directory found, and no target references specified.`

Comment: If you've installed the binaries why are you trying to build again? If you want to build from source you should download the source code instead. If you have clarifications to make you should [edit] them into the question rather than adding comments

Comment: The Boost website actually mentions that the libraries I am trying to build (system and serialization) require separate builds if you scroll further down. Same for iostream and progress_options which I have already installed

Comment: They aren't header only but you don't need to build them, they're included in the binary download. If you really want/need to build them you'll need the source code, not the binary download